# Globally set lintOptions in android studio gradle file

Tags: android, gradle, module, configuration, lint

How should I set Lint Option and VersionCode/Name globally for all modules
I have 3 module and 1 application module 
for every module/build.gradle file I need to set as

```
lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
}
```

But I want to set this in project level e.g in /build.gradle 
I have try to paste above code in upper level gradle file but not work

```
allprojects {

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

**Is there any way to set this globally** ?

Comment: I have check using project.ext { var } and use It work for version code and name but not for lint option , Please let me know if it is correct way or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a new Gradle script file, e.g. `android-lint.gradle` with the following contents:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

And then add this line below `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'` (or `com.android.application`) to every module:

```
apply from: '../android-lint.gradle'
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using "apply from: "${rootDir}/android-lint.gradle" due to having some inconsistencies in module structure.